# Pipe output of one command to two others

Tags: shell, shell-script

I need to pipe the output of one command to two other commands.

```
cat filename.txt | tail -n 1
cat filename.txt | wc -l
```

Since the file is huge I want to avoid reading it twice. I checked `tee` command but it redirects output to file which I don't want. There are many related posts but did not find anything relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the last line of the file along with the line count:

```
$ cat a
aaa
bb
ccc
$
$ awk 'END{print $0; print NR}' a
ccc
3
```

Since you need them to save in variables:

```
$ out=$(awk 'END{print $0"|"NR}' a)
$ last_line=$(echo $out | awk -F"|" '{print $1}' )
$ tot_cnt=$(echo $out | awk -F"|" '{print $2}' )
$ echo $last_line
ccc
$ echo $tot_cnt
3
```

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want..and i want both in variable

Comment: how can I save it in variable?

Comment: I'm not that good in shell..I understand NR=number of records but how awk is getting last record can you please explain?

Comment: END label instructions are executed after the last line of the file is processed. Hence, inside END when you try to print $0, it ends up printing the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
{   
    {   tee /dev/fd/3 | wc -l >&4
    }   3>&1 | tail -n1
}   <filename.txt 4>&1
```

It doesn't avoid reading it twice - but on multicore systems it will likely be concurrent. The output order is in no way guaranteed, however.

Probably the fastest way to simulate what you're asking for, though, is:

```
dd bs=64k <filename.txt | tail -n1
```

`dd` will report its read/writes to stderr and *still* copy all of the file to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Let the `cat` sleep, you don't need it.

Use :

```
tail -n 1 filename.txt
wc -l filename.txt
```

Comment: Yes, but this still reads the input file twice which is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: I can't avoid cat..

Comment: @heemayl: you are perfectly right, and it is not just syntactic sugar. Measuring the performance shows that getting rid of `cat` is much faster: `tail` knows how big the file is and can be optimized to check directly at the file end before returning the last line, but it does not know how _big_ `stdin` is going to be, so it has to wait until `cat` is done before returning its answer. A similar thing applies to `wc`, which performs better against a file than against `stdin`.